# React - Store data in localStorage after click on Icon

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to save data on localStorage if the user clicked on a like button and remove it if the user unclicked it. This is my code

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
const [iconStates, setIconStates] = useState({});
...
...
...
{recipes.reduce(reduceRecipes, []).map((item, index) => (
          <Carousel.Item key={item._id}>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <Row>
            {item.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <Col sm>
                <Card key={item._id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.photo_location} />
                  <Card.Body>
                  <div className="title-container">
                    <Card.Title>
                    {item.name} 
                    <RiHeart3Fill
                    className={
                      iconStates[item._id] ? 'heart active' : 'heart'
                    }
                    onClick={() => {
                        if (menu.includes(item)) {
                          setMenu(menu.filter(menuItem => menuItem._id !== item._id));
                        } else {
                          setMenu(menu.concat(item));
                        }
                        localStorage.setItem('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));
                        setIconStates({...iconStates, [item._id]: !iconStates[item._id]})
                    }}
                  />
```

I Codesandbox version is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-water-gzs8yz?file=/src/App.js).

It doesn't work as it supposed to do now, when I click the icon on one item it doesn't get added until I click it again, and if I unclicked any item everything in the LocalStorage is deleted. can anyone elaborate on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, You can provide a link like Codessandbox to show us your code. That's will view problem more clearly.

Comment: Hi, just edited the post with the link.